# Python / create ssh connection and change a file

Tags: python, ssh

I have the following code in python:

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
try:
  if not s.login ('x.x.x.x', 'root', 'password'):
      print "SSH session failed on login."
      print str(s)
  else:
      print "SSH session login successful"
      s.sendline ('uptime')
      s.prompt()         # match the prompt
      print s.before     # print everything before the prompt.
      s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
   print "SSH conection failed"
   print str(e)
```

and I success to do ssh connection.

Now, I want to append a key to a file which already exists in my system (in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

I don't find any way to do it with the `pxssh` API. How can I do it.

Comment: Just a side note: [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org) seems to be a bit more modern and maintained - and has API support for keys, as I gather: [paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code I'll assume that you have successfully connected to the remote machine via ssh. I have used this method for a similar purpose but with different data.

```
file_data = open("/root/.ssh/authorized_keys").read()
"""manipulate the contents of the file such that the variable new_key contains
   the data you want to append to the file via ssh"""

#I'll assume the data to be abcd
new_key = "abcd"                 
#Constructing the command to pass via ssh
cmd = 'echo "' + new_key + '">>/root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
#note that I've used >> and not >, the former will append while the later will overwrite the file
#also the path given in the above command is the one on the remote ssh server and not your local machine
s.sendline(cmd)
s.prompt()
print s.before
#voilà your key is appended to the file on the remote server
#you can check that
s.sendline("cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys")
s.prompt()
print s.before
```

Hope this helps.